# Sort Array by Number and Boolean

Tags: php, sorting

I have an array, every item has a number from 1-10, and every item has boolean value.

I want to sort it, so every item with boolean is in the first part of the array, but it should also be sort by number

Example. This is simplified the initial Array

`Item1: Number 3, Boolean false
Item2: Number 8, Boolean true
Item3: Number 4, Boolean false
Item4: Number 2, Boolean true`

This Array Should look like this

`Item2: Number 8, Boolean true
Item4: Number 2, Boolean true
Item3: Number 4, Boolean false
Item1: Number 3, Boolean false`

I already got this function

`$refarr =  array_sort($refarr, 'refweights', SORT_DESC);`

which sort the Array like this

`Item2: Number 8, Boolean true
Item3: Number 4, Boolean false
Item1: Number 3, Boolean false
Item3: Number 2, Boolean true`

Is there any other way to archive what i than to split the initial Array into two Arrays (Boolean True and false), sort this by number, and bring them back together?

Comment: You’ll want to use `usort` here, with your own little comparison function that compares two items by your specified criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `usort` with custom sorting...

```
<?php

$arr = array(
    array(2, false),
    array(2, true),
    array(3, false),
    array(8, true),
    array(4, false),
    );

usort($arr, function ($a, $b){
    if ($a[0] === $b[0]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a[0] < $b[0]) ? 1 : -1;
});
usort($arr, function ($a, $b){
    if ($a[1] === $b[1]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a[1] < $b[1]) ? 1 : -1;
});
print_r($arr);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 
        )

)
```

Refer: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: This sort is incorrect. https://3v4l.org/qRg4J

Comment: Updated: https://ideone.com/JbJmZu

Comment: Still doesn't work. https://3v4l.org/2uZTn You should first check with truthy or falsy values and then numbers.

Comment: Updated code https://ideone.com/2b6P3Z

Comment: Does it works ?

Comment: No. it doesn't https://3v4l.org/TZiBi You are comparing booleans with < or > sign. I think it's easy to check boolean equality and then sort based on value like https://3v4l.org/bciPG